# how to configure AD with Open LDAP?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, saml, openldap

I have a multi-tool continuous delivery environment for my project. User management is happening through Open LDAP and it is SSO.
Now we want to configure the same with organizational Active directory, so that users don't have to maintain multiple user name passwords .

Can somebody please help me on how to achieve it.

-Rash

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it if it is compliant with your restrictions is to delegate the authentication operations performed on OpenLDAP to ActiveDirectory.

This way it will allow you to maintain all your configurations in OpenLDAP and your AD users will use their AD credential to authenticate.

See this tutorial to configure it : https://ltb-project.org/documentation/general/sasl_delegation